# Positive and Negative Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I've been using RegEx expressions in Python for a while and I want to find out if it possible to ask RegEx to match a line that has a value in the line but also does not have a value in the same line:

Given a line saying: `filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4`

I want to say find filename.txt that does not have option3.

I used: `^(?!.*opt3).* filename.txt.*`

I don't like how this reads BUT seams the only technique that might work

Comment: This will give you a problem if `filename` includes `opt3`

Comment: This didn't work for me.   re.search( 'FileName.abc 0 opt1 opt2 opt4', '^(?!.*opt3)FileName\.abc' ) != None

Comment: This didn't work either.  re.search( 'FileName.abc 0 opt1 opt2 opt4', '^(?!.*opt3).*(filename\.abc)' ) != None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you tried in the the comments, the first argument of [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is the pattern and the second argument is the string.

Your code might look like

```
import re
match = re.search('^(?!.*opt3)FileName\.abc', 'FileName.abc 0 opt1 opt2 opt4')
if match:
    print(re.group())
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/o0CbxA)

If the should not be opt3 in the string but opt3 can be part of a larger string, you could use lookarounds to make sure opt3 is not surrounded by non whitespace chars

```
^(?!.*(?<!\S)opt3(?!\S))filename\.txt
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
  - `(?<!\S)opt3(?!\S)` match `opt3` not surrounded by non whitespace chars
- `)` Close lookahead
- `filename\.txt` match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KytUjq/1)

Comment: OK... I see now... Basically this answer is simplest and shows the correct string in the search().  My original text had an extra character.. So close ty.

Comment: @Keith You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
^(?!.*opt3)filename\.txt
```

might simply suffice.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/gLNoDy/1/)

Just in case, `filename.txt` wouldn't be at the beginning of the string, then

```
^(?!.*opt3).*(filename\.txt)
```

would be an option to look into, as well.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/rrwtBj/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test 1

```
import re

string = '''
filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4
filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt3 opt4
 filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4
  filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt3 opt4
'''

expression = r'^(?!.*opt3).*(filename\.txt)'

print(re.findall(expression, string, re.M))
```

#### Output 1

```
['filename.txt', 'filename.txt']
```

---

#### Test 2

If you wanted to swipe the entire string, you can simply add a `.*` at the end of the expression:

```
import re

string = '''
filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4
filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt3 opt4
 filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4
  filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt3 opt4
'''

expression = r'^(?!.*opt3).*filename\.txt.*'

print(re.findall(expression, string, re.M))
```

#### Output 2

```
['filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4', ' filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4']
```

#### Test 3

```
import re

string = '''
filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4
filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt3 opt4
 filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4
  filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt3 opt4
'''

expression = r'(?m)^(?!.*opt3).*filename\.txt.*'

print(re.findall(expression, string))

for item in re.finditer(expression, string):
    print(item.group(0))
```

#### Output

```
['filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4', ' filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4']
filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4
 filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4
```

Comment: interesting that re.findall() is finding it but it requires the 3rd parameter and the re.M.  Otherwise it returns an empty list.  re.search() won't find it at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single regex, then your approach is how I would do this, but you should place word boundaries around the various terms:

```
^(?!.*\bopt3\b).*\bfilename.txt\b.*$
```

You could also do this using two separate calls to `re.search`, e.g.

```
line = "filename.txt  opt1 opt2 opt4"
if re.search(r'^.*\bfilename.txt\b.*$', line) and not re.search(r'^.*\bopt3\b.*$', line):
    print("line is a match")
```